how to fix gradlew not found
I'm running a android project on docker container with this jdk version openjdk:17-jdk-slim
The android project is working with gradle version 8.5.
When I tried to build the application using ./gradlew assembleDebug command I have got this issue
./gradlew assembleDebug bash: ./gradlew: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
When I tried to use those two solutions
1st solution : using this command first : RUN sed -i 's/\r$//' ./gradlew
2nd solution : using those commands :
apt-get install dos2unix
dos2unix ./gradlew

I have got this issue
problem was found storing the configuration cache.
450.2 - Build file 'app/build.gradle.kts': failed to compute value with custom source 'org.gradle.api.internal.provider.sources.process.ProcessOutputValueSource' (output of the external process 'sh') with org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
450.2
450.2 See the complete report at file:///app/build/reports/configuration-cache/351alrem3tvz1arptw2tek2sp/dcn9ixacfqbe4do8m7ioa36so/configuration-cache-report.html
450.2
450.2 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
450.2
450.2 * Where:
450.2 Build file '/app/app/build.gradle.kts' line: 24
450.2
450.2 * What went wrong:
450.2 Process 'command 'sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
450.2
450.2 * Try:
450.2 > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
450.2 > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
450.2 > Run with --scan to get full insights.
450.2 > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
450.2
450.2 BUILD FAILED in 7m 29s
450.2 10 actionable tasks: 10 executed
450.2 Configuration cache entry stored with 1 problem

Even with using the gradlew assembleDebug command on android terminal it works fine and the build was successfully done , so I don't think that the probelem exist with app/app/build.gradle.kts file
Could you please help me resolving this problem

please add the contents of your gradlew file to the question
